# How do I view the contents of an ibdata file?

Tags: mysql

Given an `mysql` `ibdata` file (originally located at `/var/lib/mysql/` on an ubuntu server), is there any way to view it in a human readable format.

I understand that it's not possible to convert it to a CSV. It appears to be some kind of hex format.

And from what I understand, the `ibdata` file is basically the steps it would take to get the database back to it's current state.

Essentially I would like to view each of those steps. I don't have the associated `.frm` files for the tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not human readable, it's possible to convert `MySQL ibdata` files for various purposes.  Have you tried InnoDB recovery tool?  https://launchpad.net/percona-data-recovery-tool-for-innodb

Documentation is available at http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/innodb-data-recovery-tool:start

Comment: That did the job, I wasn't able to extract everything, but got me close enough